# Ion-Tabs view does not open up

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I had to change my post. my problem is the following tabs view:

```
<ion-tabs class="tabs-icon-top tabs-color-active-positive">

    <ion-tab title="Text" icon-off="ion-ios-pulse" icon-on="ion-ios-pulse-strong" ui-sref="app.pola-edit-tabs.text">
        <ion-nav-view name="tab-text"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>

    <ion-tab title="Style" icon-off="ion-ios-chatboxes-outline" icon-on="ion-ios-chatboxes" ui-sref="app.pola-edit-tabs.style">
        <ion-nav-view name="tab-style"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>

    <ion-tab title="Preview" icon-off="ion-ios-gear-outline" icon-on="ion-ios-gear" ui-sref="app.pola-edit-tabs.preview">
        <ion-nav-view name="tab-preview"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>

</ion-tabs>
```

The JavaScript file belonging to it is the following:

```
angular.module("App.Pola-Edit-Tabs", [])

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state("app.pola-edit-tabs", {
        url: "/home/pola/edit/tabs",
        abstract: true,
        templateUrl: "templates/pola_edit_tabs.html"
    }).state("app.pola-edit-tabs.text", {
        url: "/text",
        views: {
            "tab-text": {
                templateUrl: "templates/pola_edit_tabs_text.html",
                controller: "PolaEditTabsTextController"
            }
        },
        params: {
            index: null
        }
    }).state("app.pola-edit-tabs.style", {
        url: "/style",
        views: {
            "tab-style": {
                templateUrl: "templates/pola_edit_tabs_style.html",
                controller: "PolaEditTabsStyleController"
            }
        },
        params: {
            index: null
        }
    })
    .state("app.pola-edit-tabs.preview", {
        url: "/preview",
        views: {
            "tab-preview": {
                templateUrl: "templates/pola_edit_tabs_preview.html",
                controller: "PolaEditTabsPreviewController"
            }
        },
        params: {
            index: null
        }
    });
})

.controller("PolaEditTabsTextController", function () {

})

.controller("PolaEditTabsStyleController", function () {

})

.controller("PolaEditTabsPreviewController", function () {

});
```

But when i call it using `state.go`

```
angular.module("App.Pola-Edit", ["App.Pola-Edit-Tabs"])

.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state("app.pola-edit", {
        url: "/home/pola/edit",
        views: {
            "menuContent": {
                templateUrl: "templates/pola_edit.html",
                controller: "PolaEditController"
            }
        },
        params: {
            size: null
        }
    });
})

.controller("PolaEditController", function ($state, $scope) {
    $scope.title = function (index) {
        $state.go("app.pola-edit-tabs.text", {
            index: index
        });
    };
});
```

Nothign happens. The View does not show up and i have no log output. so no error and no warning. I compared each line with the example tabs project [here](http://codepen.io/mrvamsidhar/pen/Ckxlg) and for me it seems to be the exact same. So why isnt it working.

Here a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/kE5d78Fjswme9ZHhqwQC?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've noticed one problem with your tabs and routes.

You have 3 tabs in your tabs directive:

```
<ion-nav-view name="tab-text"></ion-nav-view>

<ion-nav-view name="tab-style"></ion-nav-view>

<ion-nav-view name="tab-preview"></ion-nav-view>
```

the name you set there must be used for the specific ruote in the views object:

```
.state("app.pola-edit-tabs-style", {
        url: "/home/pola/edit/tabs/style",
        views: {
            "tab-style": {
                templateUrl: "templates/pola_edit_tabs_style",
                controller: "PolaEditTabsStyleController"
            }
        }
    })
```

As you can see the second tab's name is `tab-style`.

Another thing you're missing is the abastract (base) style which loads the tabs template. You can find a sample [here](http://codepen.io/ionic/pen/odqCz).

Why would you define your routes in another module? John Papa in his [Angular Style Guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#routing) [suggests](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#style-y271) to:

> Define routes for views in the module where they exist. Each module
>   should contain the routes for the views in the module.

But you seem you're separating the base state for the tabs in 2 different modules.

I can see you're using a `menuContent`. Normally you would do that when you have a side menu. Am I right?
In case you want to mix sidemenus with tabs you might want to have a look at this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/qkHWEOnFZnYbJc2pVzJU?p=info).

There are a few problems with your code. Scripts loaded twice (ionic.bundle.js) and some other css which cannot be found.

Your state app.foo is trying to load a controller which does not exist in that module (`PolaEditController`).

Params in your states is meaningless since it's never used:

```
.state("app.tabs.text", {
        url: "/text",
        views: {
            "tab-text": {
                templateUrl: "tabs_text.html",
                controller: "PolaEditTabsTextController"
            }
        },
        params: {
            index: null
        }
```

Your abstract state for the tabs need to be loaded in a view since you're using a side menu:

```
.state("app.tabs", {
    url: "/tabs",
    abstract: true,
    views: {
    'menuContent': {
      templateUrl: "tabs.html",
      // controller: 'tabsCtrl'
    }
  }
})
```

I guess you need to read a little bit of documentation. This is the final [result](http://plnkr.co/edit/8x5oTvSaPzif7jP9CTKb?p=preview).

Comment: You cannot open abstract states. I cannot figure out what's happening in your code, to be honest. You need to create a plunker or a codepen.

Comment: i changed my post because it is a complete other problem. with the code i posted above the tabs view isnt even opening up. im sorry but i cant post a plunker because i have no idea how to map my project files to the plunker. it is a very very huge project.

Comment: Try and simplify your project in small sub-project (using plunker, maybe) so you can understand what's the real cause of your troubles.

Comment: I added a plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/kE5d78Fjswme9ZHhqwQC?p=preview if you press the "text" button - nothing happens.

Comment: using `ui-sref="app.pola-edit-tabs.text"` instead of `ng-click="title(image.index)"` also does not change anything.

Comment: Let me have a look at it.

Comment: @Mulgard: You can see my updated answer with a link to a plunker with a final result.

Comment: you helped me alot with that. the only problem was to add it to the "menuContent". Now i have another question. Is it possible to show the back button instead of the icon for the side menu?

Comment: @Mulgard: open another question. That's the way SO works. Cheers.